# SaltStack - Managed file gets written on every run, how to only write the file if there are updates?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm having some trouble where my managed files are being written on every state run, even if there was nothing that updated in the file. Oddly enough, I can't seem to find anything about stopping this from happening via google or in the salt docs.

My states is split up into init.sls to deploy the package, and config.sls to configure the package, with default and environment specific config values split out into a pillar. Examples are below.

```
Config State Example:
{% from "amq/map.jinja" import amq with context %}
camelxml_conf:
  file.managed:
    - name: {{ amq.camelxml }}
    - source: salt://amq/conf/camel.xml.tmpl
    - template: jinja
    - user: omapp
    - group: omapp
    - mkdirs: True
    - recurse:
      - user
      - group
```

---

```
Pillar Example:
default_routes:
  Route1:
    from_uri: 'activemq:inputqueue1'
    process_ref: 'myprocessor1'
    to_uri: 'activemq:outputqueue1'
  Route2:
    from_uri: 'activemq:inputqueue2'
    process_ref: 'myprocessor2'
    to_uri: 'activemq:outputqueue2'

{% if 'qa' in grains['env'] %}
env_routes:
  route1:
    from_uri: 'activemq:inputqueue3'
    process_ref: 'myprocessor3'
    to_uri: 'activemq:outputqueue3'
{% endif %}
```

---

```
Camel.xml Template Example:
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
      <!-- routes common across all environments -->
      {% for route, args in pillar.get('default_routes', {}).items() %}
        <route>
          <from uri="{{ args.from_uri }}"/>
          <process ref="{{ args.process_ref }}"/>
          <to uri="{{ args.to_uri }}"/>
        </route>
      {% endfor %}

      <!-- routes unique to this environment -->
      {% for env_route, args in pillar.get('env_routes', {}).items() %}
        <route>
          <from uri="{{ args.from_uri }}"/>
          <process ref="{{ args.process_ref }}"/>
          <to uri="{{ args.to_uri }}"/>
        </route>
      {% endfor %}
```

Am I doing anything completely wrong here? Should I not be setting values dynamically in my pillar? I'm thinking this may be why a new file is written on each state run, but am not sure.

Comment: What do you mean? There is no difference between the old and the new file, even line order? The modification time of the file is updated each time you run your state without other modification? Do you have the output of a run? What version are you using? The Salt behavior is to not update a not modified file, so if it keeps updating it, it may be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your state with test=True appended to the command it will show you a diff of the changes it's going to make. That might help you track down why it thinks a change is necessary

Comment: Thanks - this made me realize that I was using cmd.run instead of cmd.wait in my init state, and this in turn caused the config file to be seen as modified on each run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `watch` or `onchange` requisites which help in applying the changes only if there is a change.